# Php date validation not working when typing 0 before the date

Tags: php, html

I have this function to validate the date of birth and send back error message when date is correct or not.

**Here is my function**

```
function checkBirthDate($string)
{
    $matches = array();
    $pattern = '/^([0-9]{1,2})\\/([0-9]{1,2})\\/([0-9]{4})$/';
    if (!preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches)) return false;
    if (!checkdate($matches[2], $matches[1], $matches[3])) return false;
    return true;
}

//Get Parameters Passed From the JS Call to This Script
$fieldValue = $_GET["q"];
$fieldName = $_GET["q2"];
$fieldCheckBox = $_GET["q3"];

//Validate the DOB
if ($fieldName == 'stepbirth') {
    $response = "";
    foreach (explode(",", $fieldValue) as $dateString) {
        //echo $dateString;
        $birthDateLen = strlen($dateString);

        if ($dateString > 9) {
            if (checkBirthDate($dateString)) {
                //Get last 4 characters of the Date for the Year
                $year = substr($dateString, -4);
                if ($year > 1900) {
                    //Get Timestamp passed over
                    $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dateString);
                    $userDate = $dt->getTimestamp();
                    //Get Date 1 Year from Today
                    $yearTime = date(strtotime('+100 year'));
                    //If User's Date is Within 1 Year
                    if ($userDate < $yearTime) {
                        $response .= '{"code":1,"message":""},';
                    } else {
                        $response .= '{"code":0,"message":"Fill date till 365 from now"},';
                    }
                } else {
                    $response .= '{"code":0,"message":"Fill date after 1900"},';
                }

            } else {
                $response .= '{"code":0,"message":"Fill valid date in."},';
            }
        } else {
            $response .= '{"code":0,"message":""},';
        }
    }
    $response = substr($response, 0, -1);
    echo "[" . $response . "]";

}
```

Which is working fine and sending the correct response, but it has only one issue, while date starts at 0 like 01,02,03 till 09. It does not validate it always sends response code "0" and do not show error message in response, even the complete date of birth is not correct like 01/20/2018 here month is not correct. But when date starts 11/20/2018 it does correct validation and sends response code "1" and shos the message.

Can anyone help with this what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Please add some example data of what `$_GET` contains. Add an example that works and an example that doesn't. I would also recommend not building json objects manually. Just create an array with the correct structure and use `json_encode()` to turn it into json.

Comment: I've added the above duplicate because this explains what is happening in your case. The conditional `if ($dateString > 9) {` is failing. I do not know why this check is happening but if you look at the preceding code and consider what is happening it's clear you are making comparisons like `01/20/2018 > 9` and `11/20/2018 > 9`. The linked duplicate explains why it sometimes fails and sometimes passes. I do think you need to review your code because it seems unnecessarily convoluted. If you are trying to validate a birthdate I recommend searching SO for alternative examples.

Comment: There's a lot going on in the code above and you can definitely simplify and rely more on `DateTime::createFromFormat()`. Just looking at the validation steps you want to make in your code—have I missed any? *1*. Make sure date is valid according to `d/m/Y` format *2*. Make sure date is greater than `1900` *3*. Make sure date is not in the future? Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

Why not using strtotime for you value?
PHP will try to convert the date for you.
By using `date("Y", strtotime($dateString))` returns the year for you. In your case you can use the time to validate or do your things with the date.

Further by using json_encode() you can pass an array which results in an json response. So:

```
$response = array("code" => 1, "message" => "Just a message");
$actual = json_encode($response);

echo $actual; //Returns { "Code": 1, "Message": "Just a message" }
```